# What is the meaning of Initial Catalog in a Sql Server database connection string?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following connection string:

```
  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebUx-20121229234926;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebUx-20121229234926.mdf" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I'm using Entity Framework and now I would like to use Code Fist to create a new database. Can someone explain what is meant by:

```
aspnet-WebUx-20121229234926
```

Could I just create any name here as long as it is the same as the name of the file that holds the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Initial Catalog` is the name of the database to be used by the connection string, which is located on the server that was specified in the `Data Source` part of the connection string.

If there are multiple databases on the server that you have permissions to use in `Data Source` then you **have to** specify the `Initial Catalog` to help it distinguish between which one you want.

If however, there is only one database on the server specified in the `Data Source`, then you don't need to specify the `Initial Catalog`.

Personally, I would say always specify both, as adding another database onto that server that you have access to could break your application if you don't use `Initial Catalog`.